# Installing 2-node cluster of MarkLogic in docker

Tags: docker, marklogic

I'd like to install MarkLogic in docker and form a cluster i.e. two or more ML nodes instance running on the same machine. How to achieve that ?

Comment: Keep in mind a 2 node cluster may impact the clusters ability to form a quorum in case one is not available.

Comment: @MichaelGardner ok thank you. A 3 node-cluster then.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Building a MarkLogic Docker Container](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/building-a-marklogic-docker-container/) blog entry, it describes how to create and initialize a Docker image running MarkLogic.

Near the bottom of the article, it describes how to link multiple containers using the `--link` switch and `docker-compose` to assist in managing a cluster of Docker containers:

## Linking Containers

> You are the one who tells Docker how containers should communicate! When using the docker run command, you can also pass in a `--link` flag.
>
> Consider the following examples:

```
docker run -d --name=marklogic1 --hostname=marklogic1.local -p 8000-8002:8000-8002 marklogic:8.05-preinitialized

docker run -d --name=marklogic2 --hostname=marklogic2.local --link marklogic1:marklogic1 -p 18000-18002:8000-8002 marklogic:8.05-preinitialized
```

> The above creates two MarkLogic containers. The second has the `--link` flag. Docker networking sets environment variables and the */etc/hosts* file inside each container being linked along and also the linking container. This sets up the ability for Docker containers to communicate over the internal Docker network. The `--hostname` flag is used to be consistent with MarkLogic, which uses the full domain name when contacting other MarkLogic servers in the cluster. So we simply add the `.local` domain to the name of the container.
>
> Finally, note the -p flag on the second container exposes the MarkLogic’s ports in the range of 8000 to 8002 to the host computer’s ports of 18000 to 18002. Why not use the host computer’s ports of 8000 to 8002? Because the first container is already using them. Remember, Docker shares networking with the host computer! But of course, you can choose any range of open ports on your host computer to map the container’s MarkLogic ports.
>
> Now, simply point your browser to port 8001 in the first container (marklogic1) and go through the post-installation steps. Skip joining a cluster. When finished, point your browser to port 18001 for the second container (marklogic2) and go through the post-installation steps. When asked to join a cluster, simply use the host name of localhost and leave the port number at 8001. MarkLogic in the second container will contact MarkLogic in the first container. The configuration will be updated such that the marklogic2 joins the cluster with marklogic1. Create and add a third MarkLogic container, also linking it to marklogic1:marklogic1 and marklogic2:marklogic2 and you’ll soon have a proper 3-node MarkLogic cluster!

## Using docker-compose

> Docker has created another tool to aid in managing clusters of Docker containers. `docker-compose` has commands to create multiple containers and network them together. You can then create them, start them and stop them using `docker-compose` commands. Docker uses a file called `Dockerfile` to build containers. `docker-compose` uses a file called `docker-compose.yml` to build networks of containers.

`docker-compose` is available as a [separate download](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

Comment: It may also be worth visiting https://hub.docker.com/_/marklogic, and signing up for free (both for Docker Hub, and the MarkLogic Developer images) if you haven't already. It gives you access to developer images, but also provides instructions, and an example cluster docker-compose file.